# Write a program that prompts for the lengths of the sides of a triangle and reports the three angles

Tags: java

Write a program that prompts for the lengths of the sides of a triangle and reports the three angles.

I am not getting angles that equal to **180**, and for some cases I am getting **NaN** for some angle values.

My code is shown below

```
public static int getSideA() {
    System.out.println("What is the length of side a?");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = console.nextInt();
    return a;
}

public static int getSideB() {
    System.out.println("What is the length of side b?");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int b = console.nextInt();
    return b;
}

public static int getSideC() {
    System.out.println("What is the length of side C");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = console.nextInt();
    return c;
}

public static void giveSides(int a, int b, int c) {
    double angleA = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a^2 - b^2 - c^2) / (-2.0 * c * b)));
    double angleB = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((b^2 - a^2 - c^2) / (-2.0 * a * c)));
    double angleC = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((c^2 - a^2 - b^2) / (-2.0 * a * b)));
    System.out.println("The three angles are: " + angleA + " " + angleB + " " + angleC);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = getSideA();
    int b = getSideB();
    int c = getSideC();
    giveSides(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your getSideA/B/C doesn't accept negative or zero value for the side to make the program more robust to faults. Not sure if this will fix the issue I believe coming from the logic but may avoid you the NaN errors

Comment: Why do you have 3 methods that do the same thing (asking for the user to input an integer)? It would be clearer if you had a single method `getSide(String name)`.

Comment: @Abrikot Hello. Each one of the methods uses the scanner to return a different value from the user. Is it possible to use the same scanner to get the three values in the same method?

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA Hello. There is still the problem of the degree values not equaling to 180.

Comment: @denominator7 > When calling a method, each of its variables are renewed. Thus, this is not the same scanner that is used. Besides, a `Scanner` can be used more than once to get many values.

Comment: @Abrikot Thanks for the reply. I am learning this as of now. Could you please show how I can use the same scanner in one method to return 3 different integers from user? Thanks

Comment: @denominator7 > Doing something like that:
    `public static int getSide(String name) {
        System.out.println("What is the length of side " + name + "?");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        return console.nextInt();
    }`
and calling it:
    `public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = getSide("a");
        int b = getSide("b");
        int c = getSide("c");

        giveSides(a, b, c);
    }`

Comment: You might want to consider the edge case of `a=1, b=1, c=2`. This should give an error because it's not a valid triangle, but the code as fixed in the answer gives `a` and `b` as 0 and `c` as 180.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in these three lines:

```
double angleA = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a^2 - b^2 - c^2) / (-2.0 * c * b)));
double angleB = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((b^2 - a^2 - c^2) / (-2.0 * a * c)));
double angleC = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((c^2 - a^2 - b^2) / (-2.0 * a * b)));
```

`^2` does not mean "squared". It means "bitwise XOR 2". You need to use `a*a` or `Math.pow(a, 2)` for "a squared".

So the three lines should be:

```
double angleA = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a*a - b*b - c*c) / (-2.0 * c * b)));
double angleB = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((b*b - a*a - c*c) / (-2.0 * a * c)));
double angleC = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((c*c - a*a - b*b) / (-2.0 * a * b)));
```

Also, the `getSideX` methods could be combined into one and the scanner could be extracted to the class level:

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int getSide(String name) {

    System.out.println("What is the length of side " + name + "?");

    int a = console.nextInt();
    return a;
}
```

Your `main` method now looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = getSide("A");
    int b = getSide("B");
    int c = getSide("C");

    giveSides(a, b, c);
}
```